# What are the differences between these two icons in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, icons

I was trying to figure out why my Express public folder is not working. However, I recreate the same public folder which the icon looks different from the last one and it worked. What're the differences between these two icons in vscode?

[image]

Comment: my first question is how you even made two directories under the same parent directory with the same name. I'm pretty sure a lot of operating systems prevent that. Or did you just edit two separate screenshots to go into one screenshot where it appears that way but isn't really?